# TCP: Improving reliability with a broken connection

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I'm working on an application where I need to ensure that even if the network goes down, messages will still arrive at their destination reliably, in-order, and unmodified. I've been using TCP, and up until now, I was just using a strategy of:

- If a send/receive fails, do it again until no error.
- If the remote disconnects, wait until the next connection and replace the socket I was send/receiving from with this new one (achieved through some threading and blocking to ensure it's swapped cleanly).

I recently realised that this doesn't work, as `send` can't report errors indicating that the remote hasn't received the message (cite eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585195/the-behavior-of-send-and-recv-in-socket-communication?rq=1)).

I did also learn that TCP connections can survive brief network outages, as the kernel buffers the packets until the connection is declared dead after the timeout period (cite.
 [here](https://superuser.com/questions/911808/what-happens-to-tcp-connections-when-i-remove-the-ethernet-cable)).

The question: Is it a feasible strategy to just crank the timeout period waaaay higher on both client/server side (using `setsockopt` and the `SO_KEEPALIVE` options), so that a connection "never times out"? I'd have to handle errors related to the kernel's buffer filling up, but that should be relatively simple.

Are there any other failure cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both ends doesn't explicitly disconnect, the tcp connection will stay open *forever* even if you unplug the cable. There is no timeout in TCP.

However, I would use (or design) an application protocol on top of tcp, making it possible to resume data transmission after re-connects. You may use [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) for example.

That would be much more stable because depending on buffers would, as you say, at some time exhaust the buffers but the buffers would also being lost on let's say a power outage.

Comment: Alright, just to confirm - if I `sent` some bytes and the network between nodes went down at any point within the send/receive cycle, as long as the two nodes don't explicitly disconnect, the bytes will be received correctly when the network comes back up?

Comment: as long as `send()` doesn't give you an error code, yes. If you got an error code (not 100% sure about that atm), you'll need to iteratively (have patience, no endless loop hammering) try to send it again, but you *don't* need to reconnect the socket - as long as the other hand will not explicitly close the connection.